# Need a handler. Pass the with: keyword argument or provide a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, rbenv, ruby-3

Recently I update my app from Ruby version 2.6.1  to 3.0.1 & I'm using rbenv as a version manager.

but when I try to run the rails server I got an error

```sh
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.1.3 application starting in development 
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
/home/humayun/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/rescuable.rb:56:in `rescue_from': Need a handler. Pass the with: keyword argument or provide a block. (ArgumentError)
    from /home/humayun/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/will_paginate-3.1.8/lib/will_paginate/railtie.rb:67:in `rescue_from'
    from /home/humayun/umerfarooq/Alchemy/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:2:in `<class:ApplicationController>'
    from /home/humayun/umerfarooq/Alchemy/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

I just read [Here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activesupport/lib/active_support/rescuable.rb) about the function which is causing an error on line 56.

applciation_controller.rb

```sh
 rescue_from Exception, with: :handle_exception
 protect_from_forgery prepend: true, with: :exception
 before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
 before_action :initialize_api

  def not_found
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
  end

 def handle_exception(exception = nil)
    return render_404 if [ActionController::RoutingError, ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound].include?(exception.class)
     render_500
 end
```

I think this is because of depreciation.

can anyone please tell me how to handle these errors?

Comment: do you have any `rescue_from` in your code (controllers probably) without a specific error?

Comment: @MarkJad i just check it and in my application_controller.rb I have 
 rescue_from Exception, with: :handle_exception

Comment: can you please post the render_404 and render_500 methods?

Answer (score 5):

your `handle_exception` probably will need a block that render a view or returns a status

as mentioned in the error in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb:2` you probably have a `rescue_from` without an error or a handler you need to follow any of below syntax

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from User::NotAuthorized, with: :deny_access # self defined exception
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, with: :show_errors

  rescue_from 'MyAppError::Base' do |exception|
    render xml: exception, status: 500
  end

  private
    def deny_access
      ...
    end

    def show_errors(exception)
      exception.record.new_record? ? ...
    end
end
```

as per documentation here https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from

------- **Update**:

This is due to the `will_paginate` gem that you are using that overrides the `rescue_from` [method in your controller](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/railtie.rb#L66) alongside the new ruby updates that change the behavior [around the keyword attribute](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/#delegation-ruby-3)

if your base controller `include ControllerRescuePatch` you might be able to remove it and this will fix it but not sure what will happen to your pagination.
Otherwise, hold off the ruby update until the `will_paginate` update their code to fix this

Comment: i just update my question with application_controller.rb please can you help me little more , because I'm working on client project and i dnt know well about this

Comment: @HumayunNaseer I updated with a possible fix, can you please try now?

Comment: i just replace my line with your three lines with the methods below but the errors remains same :(

Comment: I think this might be a bug related to https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/3.0.html#keyword-arguments-are-now-fully-separated-from-positional-arguments what if you remove the with and just use a block directly with the content of the methods - let me update the answer

Comment: updated, let me know if it works, if not I'm afraid this might be a bug in rails

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230885/discussion-between-mark-jad-and-humayun-naseer).

Comment: i replied in discussion please have a look

Answer (score 3):

I just try to using letest version of **will_paginate** gem and it's work for me

```
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 4.0'
```